# Sharepoint online default column value is set but not used

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I want to set the default value of a sharepoint document library column. 
I use the following code:

```
field = list.Fields.GetByTitle("fieldname");
field.DefaultValue = "the default value";
field.Update();
pnpClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

In the document library "Column default value settings" you can see that the default value is set.
But when adding a document to the library, the default value is not copied. This is caused by the fact that the option "use this default value" is not set using the code above (see screenshot)

["use default value" is not set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imb5B.png)
What i'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Also check it in Library Settings > General Settings > Column default value settings.
Click on desired Column name and set Use this default value.

So apparently you need to change the "Default Value" in two places. In the general library settings and in the specific column settings.

Hope that helps!

Comment: correct, but if I set the default value in code i cannot set "use this default value"

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/set-the-default-value-for-the-list-field-in-sharepoint-2010-using-client-object-model) is a example for setting default values for list items.

The sample is from sharepoint 2010 but it should works for both sharepoint online and 2013.

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
Web web = clientContext.Web;
List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("CustomList");
Field field = list.Fields.GetByTitle("Title");
field.DefaultValue = "Default";
field.Update();
clientContext.Load(field);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: I tested your code. The defautl value is filled, but still "use this default value" is not set. Are you sure that for sharepoint online this code should work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code：

```
//get taxonomy field 
    var taxColumn = ctx.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(ctx.Web.Fields.GetByTitle(taxFieldTitle)); 
    ctx.Load(taxColumn); 
    ctx.ExecuteQuery(); 
    //initialize taxonomy field value 
    var defaultValue = new TaxonomyFieldValue(); 
    defaultValue.WssId = -1; 
    defaultValue.Label = termLabel; 
    defaultValue.TermGuid = termId.ToString(); 
    //retrieve validated taxonomy field value 
    var validatedValue = taxColumn.GetValidatedString(defaultValue); 
    ctx.ExecuteQuery(); 
    //set default value for a taxonomy field 
    taxColumn.DefaultValue = validatedValue.Value; 
    taxColumn.Update(); 
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, but i'm missing something I think, what is termId?